# Can not create a POST body with required format in iOS 6 +

Tags: php, web-services, ios6, http-post, httprequest

I am using web services developed in PHP for my iOS app. Now I have send parameters in POST body as given by PHP developer. But I can't manage to send it in POST body in required format.
Here is the format given by PHP developer

```
       Array
(
    [key] => ecwrerwe3453453453454cea
    [secret] => 45d77657657567jghjb6ef
    [product] => Array
        (
            [name] => mobile
            [id] => 3
            [desc] => nokia c 5
            [price] => 5
        )

    [spec] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => color
                    [value] => ping
                )

        )
)
```

What I am sending to server is as given below

```
    {
    key = c435435t3tergs680;
    product =     (
                {
            id= 3;
            desc = "Test desc";
            name = "Nokia mobile";
            "price" = "987.65";
        }
    );
    secret = 43ytehgrdghd1ee0d8;
    specs =     (
                (
                        {
                key = aaaaaaaaa;
                value = aaaa;
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                key = bbbbbbbbbb;
                value = bbbbb;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

To build above POST body , I am using below code in iOS

```
NSMutableArray *specsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (ProductSpecification *prodSpecs in self.newProduct.specificationArray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *specsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [specsDict setValue:prodSpecs.name forKey:SPECS_NAME_KEY];
        [specsDict setValue:prodSpecs.value forKey:SPECS_VALUE_KEY];
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:specsDict, nil];
        [specsArray addObject:array];
    }

    NSMutableArray *productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *productDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [productDict setValue:self.newProduct.name forKey:NAME_KEY];
    [productDict setValue:self.newProduct.prodId forKey:ID_KEY];
    [productDict setValue:self.newProduct.productDescription forKey:DESC_KEY];
    [productDict setValue:self.newProduct.price forKey:PRICE_KEY];
    [productArray addObject:productDict];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:productArray,NEW_PRODUCT_ARRAY_NAME_KEY,specsArray,SPECS_ARRAY_KEY,nil];
    // Get the API keys & append it in params 
    NSDictionary *keysDictionary = [kUserDefaults getAPIKeys];
    [params setValue:[keysDictionary objectForKey:API_KEY] forKey:API_KEY];
    [params setValue:[keysDictionary objectForKey:API_SECRET_KEY] forKey:API_SECRET_KEY];

    NSLog(@"Params Dict: %@",params);
```

I am not able to send the data in required format to server. How can I send the key-value in array instead of nsdictionary ?

Can anybody tell me what's going wrong in my iOS code ?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP's print_r and iOS's NSLog _could_ be rendering slightly different output. Are you able to see the print_r result of what you are posting to the web service?

Comment: Yes. Server can get the parameters that I am sending in POST body.But it is not in the required format.

Comment: You could try formulating the POST data manually. For example: `key=ecwrerwe3453453453454cea&secret=45d77657657567jghjb6ef&product[name]=mobile&product[id]=3&product[desc]=nokia c 5&product[price]=5&spec[0][key]=color&spec[0][value]=ping`

Comment: Hi Tom, PHP developer use the above syntax while checking via web browser & he can get the data in required format. But from iOS app , I am not able to send the POST parameters ion required format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this solves your problem, but it might help you get there.

Essentially, you're re-creating the following HTML form, but from your iOS app:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="key" type="hidden" value="ecwrerwe3453453453454cea" />
<input name="secret" type="hidden" value="45d77657657567jghjb6ef" />
<input name="product[name]" type="hidden" value="mobile" />
<input name="product[id]" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input name="product[desc]" type="hidden" value="nokia c 5" />
<input name="product[price]" type="hidden" value="5" />
<input name="spec[0][key]" type="hidden" value="color" />
<input name="spec[0][value]" type="hidden" value="ping" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

When this form is submitted, the browser will submit the following in the post body:

`key=ecwrerwe3453453453454cea&secret=45d77657657567jghjb6ef&product%5Bname%5D=mobile&product%5Bid%5D=3&product%5Bdesc%5D=nokia+c+5&product%5Bprice%5D=5&spec%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=color&spec%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=ping&submit=Submit`

Or decoded:

`key=ecwrerwe3453453453454cea&secret=45d77657657567jghjb6ef&product[name]=mobile&product[id]=3&product[desc]=nokia c 5&product[price]=5&spec[0][key]=color&spec[0][value]=ping`

You could try to create this string yourself by using NSMutableString / appendFormat / whatever. Then in your (presumably) NSMutableUrlRequest, `[request setHTTPBody:[postDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

I guess your code could look something like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/api/"] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableString* postDataString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[postDataString appendFormat:@"key=%@",key];
[postDataString appendFormat:@"&secret=%@",secret];
[postDataString appendFormat:@"&product%5Bname%5D=%@",self.newProduct.name];
// etc...

[request setHTTPBody:[postDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Don't forget, you'll need to escape your values properly too.